# WSO2 API manager 4.1 Custom rate limiting - denying requests at definable time intervals

Tags: rest, web-services, wso2, wso2-api-manager, wso2-esb

Based on this [link](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/rate-limiting/access-control/#denying-requests), there are four policies for denying requests in the WSO2 API Manager.

- Block calls to specific APIs
- Block all calls from a given application
- Block requests coming from a specific IP address
- Block a specific user from accessing APIs

Based on this [link](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/design/rate-limiting/advanced-topics/custom-throttling/), The following keys can be used to create custom rate limiting policies (with Siddhi query language):

- resourceKey
- userId
- apiContext
- apiVersion
- appTenant
- apiTenant
- appId
- clientIp

I need to deny requests within specific time limits. Maybe particular hours or some specific days. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can check on Siddhi Query functions to develop your custom Rate Limiting policy in the WSO2 API Manager to perform the limiting within a specified timeframe.

Also, the mentioned requirement can be achieved by developing a Global Synapse Handler and engaging it with the API Manager server. The Synapse Handler implementation is done using Java and will get engaged with each API call invocation.

- [Siddhi Cron](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CEP420/Inbuilt+Windows#InbuiltWindows-cron)
- [Synapse Handlers in WSO2 API Manager](https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/integrate/develop/customizations/creating-synapse-handlers/)